# Wordpress user registration

Tags: wordpress

how do I restrict user to first create an account on my blog and then post/comment ?

Comment: Consider asking this question over at wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: You can also find more suitable help at the WordPress.org forums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Discussion Settings` just check the `Users must be registered and logged in to comment` checkbox.

If you want to allow anybody to register, make also sure that under `General Settings` the checkbox `Anyone can register` in the `Membership` line is checked.

There is also a Plugin that allow user to use OpenID to login to your blog: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/openid/

Answer (score 0):

On my Wordpress Blogs, I make sure that the following options are set:

Under `Settings` / `Discussions` set the following options:

- Check `Users must be registered and
  logged in` under `Other comment
  settings`
- Check `Anyone posts a comment` and `A
  comment is held for moderation` under
  `E-mail me whenever`
- Check `Comment author must have a
  previously approved comment` under
  `Before a comment appears`

This way only registered users who have previously commented under your moderation will have the rights to comment freely.

I also install a plugin called `BanHammer` (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ban-hammer) which allows you to check registered users against a known database of spammers, and also allows you to specify your own domains or email addresses to stop spammers from registering (it picks up the list from Wordpress' `Comment Blacklist` which is on the `Discussion Settings` Page.

Also, don't forget to Activate `Akismet` which will hopefully trap some (if not all) of the comment spam.